# Column Width Animating XAML

Tags: vb.net, xaml

I have a three column grid with the following contents:

Column 1: Child Grid (Width: Specific)

Column 2: TextBox (Width: Auto)

Column 3: Child Grid (Width: Auto)

I was wondering, in pure XAML and with no behindcode, if it is possible to animate the third column to "grow" and the second column to "shrink" to fit it.

If behindcode is required for this, is there any chance someone could point me in the way of a VB method?

I have tried all the doubleanimations I can think of, and I have looked for a way of shrinking the textbox relative to its current width, which would might solve the problem, to no avail.

Thanks in Advance,

Freddy.

Answer (score 1):

Column widths are defined as `GridLength` not `double`, which is why you won't get the results you're looking for with any of the `DoubleAnimation` variants. There's no built in implementation but making a `GridLengthAnimation` is not that hard and there are plenty of examples out there (though I don't know about one in VB).

Here's one example: http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2007/08/20/gridlength-animation/

Most of the code is boilerplate that should be easy for you to write in VB on your own and the important bits (i.e. `GetCurrentValueCore`) should translate with very minimal changes.

Comment: is there a version of that custom class for use in a windows 8 app?

Comment: No. The base AnimationTimeline class used doesn't exist in WinRT XAML.